# Galois extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

> Determine whether the following fields are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (a) $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )$, where $\omega  = exp(2\pi  i/3)$.
>
> (b) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$.
>
> (c) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$.

I have already shown that (a) is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, and (b) is not. For (c), I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7})$, but I couldn't conclude. Any hint?

**PS:**  Use only results of automorphism and Galois extensions.

> **Definition.** Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $F$. Then $K$ is Galois over $F$ if $F = \mathcal{F}(Gal(K/F))$.

$\mathcal{F}$ is the fixed field.

> **Proposition.** *Let $K$ be a field extension of $F$. Then $K/F$ is Galois if and only if $|Gal(K/F)|=[K:F]$*.

Comment: Are you sure (a) is not Galois? Looks cyclotomic (and of degree 2) to me.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, Sorry, I should not have been clear... (a) is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. The automorphism are identity and complex conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}$ is $x^4-24x^2+4$. Now show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7})$ is the splitting field of this polynomial.

**Edit:** Since you can't use splitting fields, here is another way to do it.
We can check pretty easily that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $(1, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, \sqrt{35} )$.

Let $\sigma \in Aut(K/\mathbb{Q})$. Then $\sigma$ is uniquely determined by its action on $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{7}$.

If $\sigma(\sqrt{5})=a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{7} +d\sqrt{35}$, then we have
$$
5=\sigma(\sqrt{5})^2=(a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{7} +d\sqrt{35})^2
$$
By equating coefficients we see that $b^2=1$, $a=c=d=0$ and thus $\sigma(\sqrt{5})=\pm \sqrt{5}$.

By the same reasoning, $\sigma(\sqrt{7})=\pm \sqrt{7}$.

We then get $4$ distinct automorphism and thus $K$ is Galois.

Comment: Nice proof! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$c)$ is the splitting field of $X^2-5$ and $X^2-7$ so it is a normal extension, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect, it is separable and henceforth Galois.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma$ be a homomorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5,\sqrt7)$ into $\mathbb C$. Clearly $\sigma$ sends $\sqrt5$ to $\pm\sqrt5$ and $\sqrt7$ to $\pm\sqrt7$, so it sends a linear combination $a+b\sqrt5+c\sqrt7$ to another linear combination $a'+b'\sqrt5+c'\sqrt7$. This shows that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5,\sqrt7)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Thus $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5,\sqrt7)/\mathbb Q$ is a normal field extension.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, very good solution. But my professor wants to be solved using only results of automorphisms and Galois extensions. Normal and separable extensions were taught later.  Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @LucasCorrêa May I suggest you to put your definition of a Galois extension here, so that we know what we shall prove? I am using the definition that a Galois extension is a normal and separable extension. Thanks.

Comment: You are completely right. I updated.